# CSS submit button weird on Iphone

Tags: html, css

A line like a border-right added on iPhone button submit, it's working fine on Android

[image]

I tried this property but it's still not working

```
-webkit-appearance: button;
```

The HTML of the button

```
<button
    id="ta-quantity-selector__custom-ok"
    className="QuantitySelectorCustomField__button-ok"
    type="button"
  >
    OK
  </button>
```

Do you have any fix for this issue, please?

Comment: Have you tried `button{outline: none;}` or `button{ width: 100%; }` ?

Comment: please show your css for the button

Comment: It's working using width: 100%; thank you

Answer (score 1):

I dunno the structure of your html. But can you try something like this?
The trick is first spacing them apart, then specifying the button width and finally, setting the input to take up the remaining space.

```css
.field {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 20rem;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.text-field {
  flex: 1;
}
label {
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}
input {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}
button {
  width: 5rem;
  border: none;
  background-color: green;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <div class="text-field">
    <label>Choose a quantity</label>
    <input type="text"/>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">OK</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used Arman Ebrahimi's answer it's working using

```
button{ width: 100%; }
```

Thank you Arman Ebrahimi

Comment: Welcome, Ahmed :) Thank God that it was solved